# How to do RSpec of validators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created a validator file and written the validation of the model in that validator file and, I want to do Rspec of that validator for each attribute how can I do?

```
#This is my validator
# my path   app/models/validators/book.rb
class Validators:: Book
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :title

  # initialize attributes
  def initialize(book = {})
    unless book.class.name == "book"
    raise "Argument is not of Book model object."
  end

  # loop through each user attribute and assign to its relevant attribute of validation class
  book.attributes.each do |name, value|
    # assign an existing attribute to validator class with the value
    if self.respond_to? name
        send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end
  validates_length_of :title, minimum: 2, maximum: 8
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I made the solution to my problem.
Thanks for the help.

```
# And path of this file is spec/models/validators/book_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Validators::Book do
   it {should validate_length_of(:title).is_at_most(64), allow_value(nil).for(:user_lastname)}
end
```

Comment: that's the nice try and try you definitely a success.

Answer (score 0):

Thoughbot's [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem provides some nice ways to test validations:

```
RSpec.describe Robot, type: :model do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:arms) }
end
```

Comment: This I have used but it is working for only model not for validator